# Snowflake Credit Usage too high compared to query runtime

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking at the queries performed against my warehouse and finding the credit calculation I'm using doesn't add up to what's being shown in snowflake. As I understand it, it is supposed to use credits per second of query time with a minimum of 60s. So if a query runs for 5s it would use 60s worth of credits, but if a query runs for 61s it will use 61s worth of credits.

Looking at the query history, limiting only to queries performed on my warehouse, I am only seeing 5 queries for the hour in question (12).

These queries copy their results into an S3 bucket in my AWS account.

[image: query history]

If I take the starts and ends of each of these queries and chart time, I am only seeing a total of 455 seconds of query time. With the X-Small warehouse that I'm using (1 credit per hour), that should be only `0.126` credits used for that hour.

[image]

But I am seeing 0.66 credits used here:

[image]

What am I missing about snowflake credit usage? Why does it appear that I am using more credits than I should?

Comment: Snowflake doesn't meter by query times. It meters by the sizes and times warehouses run. If you have a running warehouse with no active query, it's still on the meter. You may or may not want to have the warehouse suspend quickly when done with a query. The main reason to keep it running while waiting for another query is because it keeps its cache. I recommend discussing how Snowflake bills and usage considerations with your Sales Engineer.

Comment: You have to consider the time your warehouse's nodes have been running, not the queries. And check what your warehouse's AUTO_SUSPEND option is set to - the lowest you can set it is 60 seconds btw.

Comment: @FrancescoQuaratino and Greg Pavlik - That makes more sense. We will try setting it to 60s and see how that affects query performance

Comment: It's also possible to set it lower than 60 seconds using SQL. Using `AUTO_SUSPEND = 1` will set it to one second, but there's no guarantee on how quickly Snowflake will shut it down when set under 60 seconds -- it could take 10, 30 or 50 seconds to shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving answer from comments to an actual answer (for completeness):

- Snowflake costs don't reflect query runtimes, but warehouses being run.

`AUTO_SUSPEND` can be set to 60 seconds (or less) to more closely match the duration of queries.

You can refer to the official Snowflake documentation for more details:

- [Virtual Warehouse Credit Usage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#virtual-warehouse-credit-usage)
- [How are Credits Charged for Warehouses?](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#how-are-credits-charged-for-warehouses)